Class in DLL crashes application
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit), I am trying to add classes to a DLL. Previously I have created a DLL which contains string resources and this works fine.  However any attempt at adding a class, even the simplest example, crashes. Here is my demo DLL class:
namespace SimonP {
    public class clsTest {
        public static void ShowName() {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}

This is the project (.sln) file:
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.8.34525.116
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SimonP", "SimonP.csproj", "{A483645B-2014-47B0-BD80-DA56F4356D3F}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {A483645B-2014-47B0-BD80-DA56F4356D3F}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {A483645B-2014-47B0-BD80-DA56F4356D3F}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {A483645B-2014-47B0-BD80-DA56F4356D3F}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {A483645B-2014-47B0-BD80-DA56F4356D3F}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {C307CDC2-0CE5-46C5-9B0F-5BD811779D98}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal

In my C# application, at the top of FrmMain.cs:
using SimonP;

Later in the FrmMain constructor:
public FrmMain() {
    try {
        SimonP.clsTest.ShowName();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("HACK");
    }
}

I've built this and am running it only in the debugger, but as soon as I start debugging I get:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=Project
  StackTrace:
   at Project.FrmMain..ctor() in C:\LocalDev\VisualStudio\Project\FrmMain.cs:line 55
   at Project.Program.Main() in C:\LocalDev\VisualStudio\Project\Program.cs:line 24

I've searched online for demos and examples and I really can't see what I've done wrong.
When running in debug I've tried to add a Watch to 'SimonP.clsTest.ShowName' the Value shows:
error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I just create a simple Console project, added the reference to the DLL and the exact same call, it worked with no exceptions.
I then create another project this time a Windows Forms App (.NET Framework), added the reference to the dll and the same call to Form1.cs Form1() after InitializeComponet() and I get:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=SimonPApp
  StackTrace:
   at SimonPApp.Form1..ctor() in C:\LocalDev\VisualStudio\SimonP\SimonPApp\Form1.cs:line 17
   at SimonPApp.Program.Main() in C:\LocalDev\VisualStudio\SimonP\SimonPApp\Program.cs:line 16

SimonPApp project properties, Application, Target framework:.NET Framework 4.7.2
Build Platform:Active (Any CPU)
Platform target:x64
Prefer 32-bit:unchecked

We usually talk about "projects" and "dependencies", "dll"s are just the output of building projects, one of several possible outputs. So you probably want to show your projects structure, and the dependencies of each project. You might also want to check the guide on solutions and projects.

I would suggest you to check if the target framework of your projects match (net8.0).

@scaler, yes they do, thats one of the first times I did, they are the same net8.0

Just looked at your solution file. Since there is only the SimonP project is I assume you have a 2nd solution with the 'Project' project in. This solution file and the two csproj files would be a good share.

@scaler, there is only one .csproj file and because its an existing project own by the company I work for I cannot post it all.

FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC is the Project-type GUID for the old-style of .csproj files (y'know, the ones with dozens of unnecessary properties) - whereas as you're targeting .NET 8 then your project-type-GUID should be 9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556 - I'm not saying this is the cause of the problem, but it indicates that you likely have an old-style .csproj targeting .NET Framework 4.x that is partially (i.e. incorrectly) trying to target .NET 8.

@Dai, this is entirely generated by MSVS Professional 2022.

@SPlatten What does that have to do with anything?

@Dai, I can't just make up a GUID, where does it come from?

@SPlatten I don't think you understand what I wrote in my comment...

Can you share the .csproj files, the top part where .net framework and such is specified, of both the application and class library projects? That specific exception mentioning that specific dll is 99.99% because you have different target runtimes for those assemblies.

Check the Plattform Target of your projects. BadImageFormat Exceptions typically points to a bitness mixup (64bit vs 32bit).

@SPlatten sorry but what you are listing above just not seems consistent and does not match what you state in the comments.

@SPlatten - open your existing (company) project in isolation and open the project properties. Tell us exactly what is shown in the Application > Target framework and under Build > Platform target and Prefer 32-bit, for each available combination of Configuration and Platform.

@NeilT, please see edits.

@SPlatten Did you recently add any NuGet package-reference or manually-added assembly-references to your project?

@Dai, sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by NuGet package?  To try and find the problem I tries creating a new project with nothing in it, then adding my dll as a reference, I get the exactly same problem, it crashes.  I can get string references from the dll, but as soon as a try to call a static class function it crashes.

Oh, that DLL is the problem: I'll bet that your "my DLL" targets .NET 8 but you're trying to load it into a .NET 4.7.2 project, that's why it fails. You need to change your "my DLL" to target .NET Fx 4.x, not 8.

@Dai, looking at the dll project, the Target framework option I only have listed: .NET 5.0, .NET 6.0, .NET 7.0, .NET 8.0, then .NET Core 1.0 to .NET Core 3.1

That's because VS doesn't support converting between .NET Framework projects and .NET Core+ (and .NET 5+) projects. You'll need to create a new project from scratch that targets .NET Framework 4.x and move your files over. (When you use the "New Project" window, make sure you choose "Class Library (.NET Framework)" and not "Class Library").

@Dai, thank you so much, that has resolved the issue, please create an answer and I will tick it off!

You want to avoid using dlls as references as much as possible. Prefer to use either project references, or nuget (package) references. This is especially true if you have own both projects.

Your exception message reveals a hint to solving the problem:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException
 HResult=0x80070002
 Message=Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.



System.Runtime, Version=8.0.0.0 refers to a BCL assembly from .NET 8.0, which the CLR is saying it can't find...

...this specific error mostly (only?) happens when the entrypoint program (i.e. the .exe with the Program.Main() method) is running in an older version of .NET and tries to load and run a .dll file targeting a newer version of .NET.


Your .sln file has this line: Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SimonP", "SimonP.csproj"

...which tells us that your SimonP.csproj project file targets .NET Framework 4.x (because FAE04EC0... is the well-known-GUID for .csproj files predating the newer "SDK-style" .csproj) and these project-files cannot reference .NET 8.
...which tells us that SimonP.csproj is likely targeting .NET Framework 4.x and trying to load a .dll which targets .NET 8.0, and that's going to fail.


Therefore, either:

Migrate SimonP.csproj to an SDK-style project file and change the <TargetFramework> to net8.0.
...or update the .csproj for your hitherto unnamed .dll file to target .NET Framework 4.x or .NET Standard 2.0 instead of .NET 8.0.



